# <Enter> key triggers "Next" button in multiple pages form

Tags: cognito-forms

Impossible to go to the next line in a multiple line textbox because <kbd>Enter</kbd> key triggers the "Next" button.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a developer at Cognito Forms. Unfortunately, there is a problem with our keyboard navigation logic for multi-page forms as it relates to multi line textbox. We are currently working hard on our localization support release that will include a fix for this issue. We apologize for this inconvenience.

Comment: Our international release is now live, which includes fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you can use the Alt+Enter ([like in Excel](http://lifehacker.com/241133/excel-tip--wrap-text-as-you-type-with-alt-enter)) or Ctrl key to go to the next line instead of going to the next page.

Comment: Hi, thanks. True that Alt/Ctrl+Enter won't trigger the Next button, but it won't insert a line break neither (using Firefox 35.0.1).